# Do I need to restart/reload apache when adding a configuration file under /etc/httpd/conf.d

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, configuration, httpd.conf

Do you need to restart/reload Apache when adding a configuration file under /etc/httpd/conf.d?

I know that editing the httpd.conf need a restart or a reload but unsure if file placed in the conf.d need apache to get restarted.

Thanks for the help

EDIT: I was under the impression that addition to /conf.d would need a regular/graceful restart but several times configuration files I've added to that directory made an effect without having to restart. This is the reason that led me to ask this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. `conf.d` files are included in Apache's configuration with a line like:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

so changes are only noticed when the main configuration is reloaded. Note you can also use the 'graceful' restart (`/etc/init.d/httpd graceful` on some, `apachectl graceful` on others) to reload the configuration without dropping existing connections.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: yes, I was under the impression that it would work the same as the main configuration but I had my share of suspicion today so I decided to check out with you guys.